# jQuery submitting only first form

Tags: jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I have the following code:

```
var onLoadRecaptcha = function () {
    $('form').each(function (id, el) {
        $(el).ready(function () {
            var submit = function () {
                $(el).submit();
            }
            grecaptcha.render(
                $(el).find('.recaptcha').get(0),
                {
                    'sitekey': '6LeDwBoUAAAAANMD7VBNK2F2agKXl6rduUlelf5U',
                    'callback': submit,
                    'size': 'invisible'
                }
            );
        });
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('form').each(function (id, el) {
        $(el).find('button').click(function () {
            grecaptcha.execute();
        });
        $(el).submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var _data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: _data
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                alert(response);
                notifySuccess("Já recebemos sua história! Obrigado por compartilhá-la conosco!");
                $(el).find('textarea').val(' ');
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                notifyAlert(data.responseText);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using Google's reCaptcha, and basically I made that every form in my site (that is basically a list of identical forms) execute the captcha before submitting the form through AJAX. Although it works in the sense that every form button does call reCaptcha window, after the reCatpcha is solved, it doesn't matter which button has been pressed, it is always the first form that is submitted.

It's like the `$(el).submit()` on line 5 everytime returns the first form instead the current form (`el`) of the iteration.

Edit: As requested, I'm attaching my **index.php** file:

```
<!doctype html>

<?php
    //  error_reporting(0);

    require_once('scripts/connect.php');
    //require_once('scripts/fb.php');

    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `personas`");
?>

<html class="no-js" lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Campanha Anti-bullying | UNASP-EC</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Uma campanha anti-bullying bem bacaninha">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.html5 || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/html5shiv.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <section>
            <div class="fill-viewport cover d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center text-uppercase container" style="background-color: #000; color: #FFF">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="images/cover_text.png" alt="Bullying, esta brincadeira não tem graça!" />
            </div>
        </section>

        <section> <!-- Apresentação -->
            <div class="container my-5 text-justify stylize-text">
                <p>O sol queimava, mas dentro da menina magra e de cabelos crespos existia uma tempestade provinda do Alasca. O céu se estendia num azul pintado de anil, porém, a menina tímida de pequeno porte, o enxergava cinza. Os pássaros cantavam, no entanto, a menina de óculos e pele negra ouvia apenas um tom dissonante. Talvez hoje o som seja algo semelhante ao da trilha de Bernard Herrmann no filme Psicose.</p>
                <p>— Mãe, me dá R$0,50? — perguntou a pequena de oito anos.</p>
                <p>— Por que você quer esse dinheiro? — retrucou a mãe desconfiada.</p>
                <p>— Por nada mãe, eu só quero — respondeu, agora com os olhos lacrimejados.</p>
                <p>A mãe não tinha ideia do que acontecia e atordoada com os fatos relatados pela filha, se viu sem forças para continuar o caminho tortuoso até a escola.</p>
                <p>— Mãe ela me bate quando não dou o dinheiro e todos os dias eles me xingam e me deixam sozinha no recreio.</p>
                <p>O trecho acima poderia ser facilmente confundido com aquelas histórias ficcional, não fosse um fato vivido por 46,6% dos alunos entrevistados pelo Instituto Brasileiro de Geografia e Estatística (IBGE). O último senso confirmou o crescimento significativo desde o último levantamento feito em 2012, onde apontou 35,3% o número de vítimas nas escolas. De acordo com a pesquisa, 7,4% dos entrevistados atribuíram a aparência como principal motivo para as agressões.</p>
                <p>De acordo com o Código Civil Brasileiro, o <i>bullying</i> é crime e resulta em pena ao agressor, podendo ser advertência ou até mesmo restrição de liberdade. Alessandra Borelli, advogada e coordenadora do <i>Manual de Boas Práticas para Uso Seguro das Redes Sociais</i> da Ordem dos Advogados do Brasil de São Paulo (OAB/SP) e coordenadora do guia <i>Conhecendo para Prevenir bullying< e Cyberbullying</i>, explica as consequências de causar dano moral ou físico ao outro e lembra ser obrigação do agressor, dos pais ou até mesmo da escola reparar a ofensa. “Logo, se um menor for responsável pela prática de <i>bullying</i>, muito embora a legislação privilegie a adoção de medidas voltadas à orientação e resgate da boa disciplina, nada impede que a vítima do <i>bullying</i> promova medidas legais buscando a reparação dos danos suportados”, destaca. Ainda de acordo com Alessandra é responsabilidade de todos, família e escola, prestar ajuda necessária a vítimas de <i>bullying</i>, com o intuito de aliviar as consequências da agressão. “Considerando os aspectos morais que alicerçam as relações entre pais e filhos, alunos, escola e sociedade em geral, todos somos responsáveis e se, ao notarmos sinais de vítimas ou agressores em nossos filhos e alunos, devemos agir tempestivamente. Famílias e escolas precisam caminhar juntas”, pontua.</p>
                <p>O Centro Universitário Adventista de São Paulo (Unasp), campus Engenheiro Coelho, entende o <i>bullying</i> como um problema real na vida de crianças e jovens e por esse motivo, aderiu à campanha “Essa brincadeira não tem graça”, com o objetivo de conscientizar vítimas e agressores, alunos de escolas e universidades públicas e privadas para a luta contra o <i>bullying</i>.</p>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section> <!-- Imprensa -->
            <div class="container py-5">
                <h1>Imprensa</h1>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section> <!-- Eu Cuido de Você -->
            <div class="container py-5">
                <h1>Eu Cuido de Você</h1>
                <p class="text-justify stylize-text">Você acompanhou histórias reais de brincadeiras sem graça, mas isso não precisa continuar. Nós entendemos o momento difícil e delicado que envolve uma agressão, mas você deve saber que não está sozinho. O Unasp preparou uma equipe de psicólogos para te ajudar. Tudo o que você precisa fazer é nos contar sua história. Fique a vontade e desabafe nos comentários abaixo sobre o que você enfrenta em seu dia-a-dia. Fique tranquilo, pois não vamos contar para ninguém. Queremos cuidar de você!</p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled form-list">
                    <?php while ($persona = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>

                        <li class="card card-inverse rounded-0 mb-4" style="background-color: #333;">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <form id="story-<?php echo $persona['id']; ?>" action="scripts/story_submit.php" method="post" class="h-100">
                                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $persona['id']; ?>" />
                                    <div class="d-flex form-body">
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                                            <img src="./images/personas/<?php echo $persona['image'] ?>" alt="" />
                                            <span class="persona-caption"><?php echo $persona['name']; ?></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-flex flex-column w-100">
                                            <textarea name="story" class="form-control" maxlength="500" required></textarea>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="recaptcha"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </section>

        <!-- Notify Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="notify-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog " role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body alert mb-0">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onLoadRecaptcha&render=explicit" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    $res->free();
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

If you want, you can also see the site in question [here](http://unasp-ec.edu.br/contraobullying).

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML?

Comment: Yes, I can, but it's a little confusing. Going to edit it.

Comment: @JoeLissner I just updated my question. You can also see the site here: http://unasp-ec.edu.br/contraobullying

Comment: I would put some console logs on the button clicks and form submits to see the order of when things are happening. I put a breakpoint on the ajax call and it was called 4 times...

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: for example, after `var submit = function () {` and `$(el).find('button').click(function () {` and `$(el).submit(function (event) {` I would put something like `console.log('submitted form: ', id)` So that you can see when which form is being submitted. Then you can try and narrow down the culprit

Comment: @JoeLissner I think i discovered the problem, thanks for your help. Anyway, my previous question was about "how do you discovered that 4 ajax call has been made?"

Comment: Oh, if you go into the dev tools of your browser (at least try for the main browsers) there is a debugger tab, and you can put breakpoints where you want to pause your code and see what's going on. I put one on the ajax call and noticed that it stopped there 4 times, when I expected to only happen once.